# Mail not getting sent through AWS Glue Python job

Tags: email, smtp, attachment, aws-glue, mime

I am trying to send a mail through an AWS Glue job. The mail will have multiple number of attachments that it gets from the s3 bucket. According to the logs, it is running until server.login(). It is failing in the server.sendmail() function.
Following is the code -

```
def sendEmail(TO, SUBJECT, BODY_HTML):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
    msg['From'] = SENDER
    msg['To'] = ','.join(RECIPIENT + TO)
    part1 = MIMEText(BODY_HTML, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('sample-bucket')
    for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Delimiter='/', Prefix='sample-folder/'):
        filename =  ((obj.key).split("/")[1])
        s3_object = s3_obj.s3_get_object(sample-bucket, 'sample-folder/'+ filename)
        body = s3_object['Body'].read()
        part = MIMEApplication(body, filename)
        part.add_header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment', filename=filename)
        msg.attach(part)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST, PORT)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(USERNAME_SMTP, PASSWORD_SMTP)
        server.sendmail(SENDER, RECIPIENT, msg.as_string()) ***--Error***
        server.close()
        print (msg)
        print ("Email sent")
```

I am getting the following error -

> Error: (554, b'Transaction failed: Expected '=', got "null"')

What is the issue?

Comment: What is the SMTP `HOST`?

Comment: @stdunbar It is an AWS host

Comment: How about the `SENDER`?  Make sure that it looks good and that there are no space characters.

Comment: @stdunbar Yes, everything looks good.

Comment: Have you tested this on local machine / aws lambda first?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy Yes

Comment: Try a web search of that SMTP error code and message. I got a few hits, e.g., for magento, but I don't know your setup well enough to recommend anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. The problem was with the way files were read from s3. The output of the first iteration was -

> sample-bucket/sample-folder/

So, it was taking a null object and failing. So, I just skipped the first object in the iteration and carried out the whole thing. It worked.
Please find the final code below -

```
def sendEmail(TO, SUBJECT, BODY_HTML):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
    msg['From'] = SENDER
    msg['To'] = ','.join(RECIPIENT + TO)
    part1 = MIMEText(BODY_HTML, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('sample-bucket')
    **it = iter(bucket.objects.filter(Delimiter='/', Prefix='sample-folder/'))
    next(it, None)
    for obj in it:**
        filename =  ((obj.key).split("/")[1])
        s3_object = s3_obj.s3_get_object(sample-bucket, 'sample-folder/'+ filename)
        body = s3_object['Body'].read()
        part = MIMEApplication(body, filename)
        part.add_header("Content-Disposition", 'attachment', filename=filename)
        msg.attach(part)
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST, PORT)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(USERNAME_SMTP, PASSWORD_SMTP)
        server.sendmail(SENDER, RECIPIENT, msg.as_string()) 
        server.close()
        print (msg)
        print ("Email sent")
```